# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^2=a^2$ when ${a_n}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$

Tags: real-analysis

Question:

Let ${a_n}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$

Prove that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^2=a^2$

Attempt:
Without using any properties of limits (this is a question in a section of the book that came before any list of any limit theorems)

By definition:

$|a_n^2-a^2|<\epsilon$

$|a_n^2-a^2|$ $\leq$ $|(a_n+a)(a_n-a)|$ $\leq$ $|(a_n+a)| |(a_n-a)|$ $\leq$

$(|a_n | + |a|)(|a_n -a|)$ $<$ $\epsilon$

And since I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, I'll subsitute that in for $|a_n|^2$ as $a^2$

$\therefore$ $a^2-|a|^2 < \epsilon$ which is true since $a^2-|a|^2$ in my case.

I wonder if this is a possible solution?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $|a_n^2 - a^2| < \epsilon$ "by definition"? That's what you need to show is true!

Comment: I thought that it was sufficient to show that if that condition holds, the limit will be convergent to $a^2$. If I attempt by using the definition $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for all $n_0 \leq n$ I'd be hard pressed to find that $n_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written down the **intuition** towards a formal proof.

You are given an $\epsilon \gt 0$, and want to show there is an $n$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $|a_n^2-a^2|\lt \epsilon$.

By your calculation, 
$$|a_n^2-a^2|\le (|a_n|+|a|)(|a_n-a|).$$
We want to make the left side "small." That will be the case if $|a_n-a|$ is small, **unless** $|a_n|+|a|$ is big. So we first want to show that after a while, $|a_n|+|a|$ cannot be big.

There are two cases, $a\ne 0$ and $a=0$.

If $a\ne 0$, there is an $N_1$ such that if $n\gt N_1$ than $|a_n-a|\lt \frac{|a|}{2}$. Thus if $n\gt N_1$, then $|a_n|\lt \frac{3|a|}{2}$, and therefore 
$$|a_n|+|a|\lt \frac{5|a|}{2}.$$

Since the sequence $(a_n)$ has limit $a$, there is an $N_2$ such that if $n\gt N_2$, then 
$$|a_n-a|\lt \frac{2\epsilon}{5|a|}.$$

Let $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$. If $n\gt N$ then $|a_n^2-a^2|\lt \epsilon$.

The argument for the case $a=0$ goes along similar lines, but is technically simpler. We leave it to you.

**Remark:** We gave the full "$\epsilon$-$N$" argument. More informally, the sequence $(|a_n|+|a|)$ is **bounded**, and $|a_n-a|\to 0$, so $|a_n^2-a^2|\to 0$.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do...without resorting to any theorems. Thanks for those useful ideas!